# Math logic - What does $X\vdash a, a \in X$ mean?

Tags: logic

Lets take, for example, the `deduction` theorem:

> For any Well Formed Formulas group $\Sigma$ and for any 2 formula $\alpha, \beta$ ,
>
> $$\Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} \vdash \beta\iff\Sigma \vdash (\alpha\to\beta)$$

**Question:**

What does $\vdash$ mean? and what does it mean in the specific example? (deduction theorem)

Please help.

Comment: It is a conspiracy theory, intended to express trivialities. They even got Latex to have a symbol for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "$\vdash$" symbols reads as "proves". That is, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha$ means that the set of sentences $\Sigma$ proves $\alpha$. Usually, this is in some proof system that's already set out, or implicitly understood in the background.

In this case, the deduction theorem just says "$\Sigma$ together with the assumption $\alpha$ can prove $\beta$ if and only if $\Sigma$ (alone) can prove $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$."

Comment: Three seconds. That's how Olympic champions win. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, all my training has come to fruition. :p

Comment: Alex, you came in second but you still got the gold... Hehe :-)

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$ means that there exists a proof from $\Sigma$ to the statement $\varphi$.

A proof is a finite sequence of well formed formulas, where we are allowed to write in the sequence either formulas which appear in $\Sigma$, or formulas which are deduced from previously written formulas (in the sequence) by using inference rules.

For example, if we have modus ponens (that is $\alpha,\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ imply $\beta$) then given a proof where $\alpha$ and $\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ has been written, we are allowed to write $\beta$.

What are the inference rules? This depends on the exact logic.