# How to understand this mathematical notation?

Tags: logic, notation, sequent-calculus

We were introduced to these rules during class and not sure how to grasp it. And what does this symbol mean ⊢?

[image]

UPDATE: Added rules 1a and 1b

Rule 1a: if the goal list has a proposition that is also in the hypothesis list, the conjecture is true.

Rule 1b: if both the goal list and hypothesis list contain propositions only, and no common propositions, the conjecture is disproven.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446178/math-logic-what-does-x-vdash-a-a-in-x-mean?rq=1 ?

Comment: It means "is *derivable*" (in the "calculus" you are wroking with).

Comment: So the above rules must be read as follows: if we have a derivation of $G$ from $H$ and $\lnot F$, then we have a derivation of $G$ and $F$  from $H$.

Comment: Can you type out the rule 1a and 1b (presumably dealing with implication).  Because depending on that the $\vdash$ can either be meant correctly as "derivation" or incorrectly as "under the assumption of"

Comment: I updated and included 1a and 2b rule. This was used to describe Wang algorithm for theorem proving. Now I understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the rules for [Sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Proving_logical_formulas).

It formalizes the rules regarding the *derivability* relation: $\vdash$ (the symbol is called "the turnstile").

Each rule is expressed in terms of *sequents*: $A_1,\ldots, A_n \vdash B_1, \ldots B_k$.

The formulas to the left of the turnstile are called the *antecedent*, and the formulas on the right are called the *succedent* or consequent.

Comment: Just to complete Mauro's answer: intuitively, a sequent $A_1,\ldots, A_n \vdash B_1, \ldots, B_k$ means that if you assume $A_1 \land \ldots \land  A_n$ then $B_1 \lor \ldots \lor B_k$ follows by necessity.

Comment: They're a rather curious sequent calculus, though, because they have the sequents with additional connectives in the _premises_ rather than the _conclusions_.